Playwright component test ct-react with problems with AWS-SDK (AWS$1L.STS.prototype)
everyone! I'm trying to use @playwright/experimental-ct-react to test a component called Footer.js which executes a function which uses aws-sdk.
When I try to execute the tests with the command
npm run test-ct src/Footer/Footer-ct.spec.js

I am having the following error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

in this line of the Playwright/.cache/assets/Footer-FgbdStX.js (file generated by Playwright for this component):
AWS$1L.util.update(AWS$1L.STS.prototype, {

But the most intriguing thing is that I don't use sts.
Has anyone experienced this or can tell me if I need to make any specific configuration for AWS in a file before this file is generated in assets?
Thank you very much! :)

Please share a [mcve] with your code and a full stack trace.
